# $(window).width() if statement running when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I am having an issue with `$(window).width` `if` statements in jQuery. For some reason my function is running even when the window width is smaller than `991` pixels however my `if` statement states that it should run if the window width is greater than `991`.

```
function ctaFixTop() {
  var mn = $("#new-car-offer-cta");
  var offerHead = $('#new-car-offer-head');
  mns = "new-car-offer-cta-active";
  var hdr = 0;
  var ctaHeight = $("#new-car-offer-cta").height();
  $('.header-wrapper, #top-bar, #new-car-back, #new-car-offer-head').each(function() {
      hdr += $(this).outerHeight();
  });
  if ($(window).width() > 991) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > hdr) {
            offerHead.css('margin-bottom', ctaHeight);
            mn.addClass(mns);
        } else {
            offerHead.css('margin-bottom', 0);
            mn.removeClass(mns);
        }
    });
  }
}
$(window).resize(ctaFixTop);
ctaFixTop();
```

As you can see the `ctaFixTop` function is being called twice, once on initial load and whenever the window is resized. When I initially load the page with a window width below 991px the function works how it should however if I then increase the windows size past 911px and size it back down under 911px the  `$(window).scroll` function will be called even when it's wrapped in the `if` statement that states that it should only run if the window width is greater than 991.

Any idea why this might be happening as I have tried trouble shooting this and simply can't understand why the function is being called even with the if statement around it.

Thanks

Comment: The scroll event is already bound with the window. Your condition will be only checked first time on page load, if the condition is true the scroll event will bind to window till you unbind it or unload the page. You should move your if condition inside the scroll even callback. Check the window width every time  when scrolled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the `scroll` event is already attached to the window and you are not removing it. What you need to do is put the

```
  if ($(window).width() > 991) {
```

inside the `.scroll()` method like this.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 991) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > hdr) {
        offerHead.css('margin-bottom', ctaHeight);
        mn.addClass(mns);
    } else {
        offerHead.css('margin-bottom', 0);
        mn.removeClass(mns);
    }
}});
```